# Parameter "n" in edarf partial dependency function

Tags: r

I am currently using the partial_dependence function within the edarf package.

Regarding the n parameter, i found the below definition from https://rdrr.io/cran/edarf/f/vignettes/edarf.Rmd.... however am still confused to exactly how i should be using/understanding this variable. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

*"The parameter n is a numeric vector of length two, which controls via its first element the size of the grid to evaluate the columns specified by the vars argument at, and the second element gives the number of rows of the other variables to sample when marginalizing the prediction function. All the actual computation is performed in the mmpf package using the function marginalPrediction. Additional arguments can be passed to this function by name (i.e., using ...)."*

Comment: See also `?partial_dependence` "two dimensional integer vector giving the resolution of the grid. the first element gives the grid on vars and the second on the other columns, which are subsampled." Perhaps also scan through the code [here](https://github.com/zmjones/edarf/blob/master/pkg/R/pd.R) and consider posting an issue to the GitHub if it's still unclear (requesting, e.g., a worked example that uses this parameter)

Comment: @MichaelChirico - thanks for your feedback... after reviewing the code, im still unsure exactly what these numbers are trying to achieve. I currently am using a data set containing ~10K rows across 9 variables. I am running 8 partial dependency plots, separate for each of the independent variables. thus i am using a vars value of 1 and then the second integer is 8 (representing the remaining  7 in dependent variables)... is this the correct way to assign these values? thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, i actually don't have any idea about the package. i was just offering some further reading in case you might be able to figure it out yourself.